# Excel IF(ISBLANK()... Not working

Tags: excel

I have a data set that I want to compute differently, depending on the input.

Here is how it looks now:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E5);F5*I5;E5*G5*H5)
```

What I want to do is that If E5 is empty, F5 should be multiplied by I5.

If not, then multiply E5*G5*H5.

The idea is to calculate daily revenues. The revenue can be either recurring each month or not.

```
E5: visitors per day
G5: conversion rate
H5: price
F5: subscribers (if recurring)
I5: recurring price
```

Problem is, regardless of what I put in E5, I won't get it to compute the value.

Thanks.

Comment: Does E5 have a formula?  "" will trip isblank as false.

Comment: Try commas instead of semicolon?

Comment: Enter the cell E5 with F2, click on "Ctrl+A" to select all and paste the input somewhere else. I bet there are trailing spaces.

Comment: @findwindow that may be te right thing to do... when having `,` as delimeter you need to use `;` as seperator... that is standart for clients like the german ones... it simply depends on the windows-setting

Comment: @DirkReichel good point.

Comment: however, i recommend to change delimeter always to point... vba will always work like that while formulas in excelsheets does not... it is also the main-error when importing number-values (which sometimes will not count as a number cus the different delimeter will switch it to text and output `#VALUE`)

Comment: @findwindow I have a European version of excel, otherwise, great point

Comment: @DirkReichel yes, I should probably change the delimeter to points instead of commas for future use and reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this method

```
=IF(E5="";F5*I5;E5*G5*H5)
```

Comment: Ah, this works like a charm. I was confused on how to tell the formula that the cell was empty. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

replace `ISBLANK(E5)` with `ISNUMBER(E5)` and swap the true/false part... or use `NOT(ISNUMBER(E5))` in condition (without swaping)